# C#: easiest way to populate a ListBox from a List

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listbox

If I have a list of strings, eg:

```
List<string> MyList = new List<string>();
MyList.Add("HELLO");
MyList.Add("WORLD");
```

Is there an easy way to populate a ListBox using the contents of MyList?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Try :

```
List<string> MyList = new List<string>();
MyList.Add("HELLO");
MyList.Add("WORLD");

listBox1.DataSource = MyList;
```

Have a look at [ListControl.DataSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx)

Answer (score 30):

You can also use the `AddRange` method

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(myList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 12):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
myListBox.DataSource = MyList;
```

Answer (score 0):

This also could be easiest way to add items in ListBox.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyList.Count; i++)
{
        listBox1.Items.Add(MyList.ElementAt(i));
}
```

Further improvisation of this code can add items at runtime.