# List<string> to listbox.Items C#

Tags: c#

I have this code

```
public List<string> GetAllFilesFromFolder(string root, bool searchSubfolders)
{
    Queue<string> folders = new Queue<string>();
    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    folders.Enqueue(root);
    while (folders.Count != 0)
    {
        string currentFolder = folders.Dequeue();
        try
        {
            string[] filesInCurrent = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(currentFolder, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            files.AddRange(filesInCurrent);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Do Nothing
        }
        try
        {
            if (searchSubfolders)
            {
                string[] foldersInCurrent = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(currentFolder, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                foreach (string _current in foldersInCurrent)
                {
                    folders.Enqueue(_current);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Do Nothing
        }
    }
    return files;
}
```

It list all files from especific directory and search for subdirectories ignoring excepetions to a `List<string>`

But How can I list the `List<string>` results to a listbox?

I tried to put

```
foreach (var foo in files)
{
    listbox1.Items.Add(foo);
}
```

after `return files;` but for some reason the appears nothing in listbox... I am using visual basic windows forms

Comment: What have you tried so far? The rest of your code isn't really important so you should probably remove that and just show your attempt to display the results of a list in a listbox.

Comment: Also, is this winforms or asp.net, asp.net MVC, etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: easiest way to populate a ListBox from a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321300/c-easiest-way-to-populate-a-listbox-from-a-list)

Comment: Well WPF or WinForms.  What have you tried?

Comment: I already updated

Comment: Could have also shown:   listbox1.Items.AddRange( GetAllFilesFromFolder("somepath", false).ToArray());

Comment: nevermind, I puted the code to list the string to listbox after I returned the files... just a dumb mistake... I am new in forum, what I do now with my question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
listBox1.DataSource = MyList;
```

(duplicate: [C#: easiest way to populate a ListBox from a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321300/c-easiest-way-to-populate-a-listbox-from-a-list))