# How to make data in the listbox appear line-by-line since listbox doesn't take "\n"?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listboxitems

I just try to read data from database line by line inside list box.
Here is my each column section that "reader.GetString" represents -
Username, Name, Surname, Department, Faculty etc.. I want them all to
appear line by line for every row not side by side with "+=" for
example;:

> Steve_J
>
> Steve Jackson
>
> Romance-Germanic Department
>
> German language and Literature
>
> and the output of currently written code blocks (all in the same line with spaces between each column) is :
>
> Steve_J  Steve  Jackson  Romance-Germanic faculty  Department of German language and Literature
>
> David_21  David   Ratchford  Faculty of Archaeology  Department of Scientific Archeology

How to go about that since we know list box doesn't take "\n"?

Source Code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection())
    {
        connect.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-9I0BNAS\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CAVID;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";

        connect.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select *  from Istifadeciler", connect))
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                     
            while (reader.Read())
            {                        
               string data = reader.GetString(0)+ " ";
               data += reader.GetString(1) + "  ";
               data += reader.GetString(2) + "  ";
               data += reader.GetString(3) + "  ";
               data += reader.GetString(4)+ "  ";
               data += reader.GetString(5) + "  ";
               data += reader.GetInt32(6).ToString()+ "  ";
               data += reader.GetInt32(7).ToString()+ "  ";

               listBox1.Items.Add(data);                        
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unclear. Where do you add the `"\n"`? `listBox1.Items.Add` will add one `ListItem` for every record.

Comment: what's not working here. I see you're concatentating all your fields and then adding them to your listbox as an item. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Doesn't look like you'd need newlines here. `listBox1.Items.Add(data);` gets executed for every row and should add a seperate entry to the listbox for each. What exactly is the output you're getting and what do you want instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354533/how-to-put-a-nnew-line-inside-a-list-box

Comment: Try to add all the values in a string list and set the list as `DataSource` to the `ListBox`. Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4321309/311255

Comment: I've just edited the question to be clearer for you

Comment: @CavidHummatov provide the output as well

Comment: @kuskmen The output is already provided.

Comment: Pretty unlikely that ListBox is the correct control to use when you write code like this. Consider ListView with View=Details.

Comment: @HansPassant how to include it into my code. Could you show as a separate answer ?

Comment: Those examples already exist, you don't need me to repeat them.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/listview-control-overview-windows-forms

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Magisch...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _51189773
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ListBox lb = new ListBox();
            lb.Items.Add("result 1");
            lb.Items.Add("result 2");
            lb.Items.Add("result 3");
            Controls.Add(lb);
        }
    }
}
```